# Oracle trigger - checking against already existing data

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I want to check a time that is being entered to see whether it is within 2 hours of any other appointments already stored.

My table is test (id, number & testdate, timestamp)

I have a trigger that checks to see whether the new time is within 2 hours of a time I specify

```
create or replace trigger "TEST_T1"
BEFORE
insert on "TEST"
for each row
when (new.testdate is not null)
begin
    if (:new.testdate BETWEEN (to_timestamp('12-AUG-12 02:00:00PM') - interval '120'   minute) 
                      AND (to_timestamp('12-AUG-12 02:00:00PM')  + interval '120' minute))
    then raise_application_error(-20634, 'This time clashes with another event.');
    end if;
end;
```

Is it possible to replace this time I put in with a list of times from the database?

With help from Michał Powaga - below - I managed to get this to work using

```
create or replace trigger "TEST_T1"
BEFORE
insert on "TEST"
for each row
when (new.testdate is not null)
begin
    DECLARE l_exists INTEGER;
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_exists FROM test WHERE testdate BETWEEN :new.testdate - interval '120' minute AND :new.testdate + interval '120' minute AND ROWNUM = 1;
        IF l_exists = 1 THEN raise_application_error(-20634, 'This time clashes with another event.');
        END IF;
    END;
END;
```

Comment: This trigger does not protect against: a) updates that could change TESTDATE to a time conflicts with another, or, b) concurrent inserts (in separate transactions) that conflict with one another.  A simpler and more robust approach (that does not use triggers) might be to put a primary key constraint TESTDATE, along with a check constraint that forces it to be a multiple of 120 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
create or replace trigger "TEST_T1"
BEFORE
insert on "TEST"
for each row
when (new.testdate is not null)
begin
    declare qty integer := 0;
    begin
        select count(*) into qty from test where testdate between (:new.testdate - 2/24) and (:new.testdate + 2/24) and rownum = 1;
        if qty > 0 then
            raise_application_error(-20634, 'This time clashes with another event.');
        end if;
    end;
end;
```

ps. please mind that I'm not an Oracle developer, so there might be errors but I think that this is the way to go :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help - it set me on the right lines.  You can't use exists there, so this is what I did

`create or replace trigger "TEST_T1"
BEFORE
insert on "TEST"
for each row
when (new.testdate is not null)
begin
    DECLARE
    l_exists INTEGER;
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_exists
        FROM test
        WHERE testdate BETWEEN :new.testdate - interval '120' minute AND :new.testdate + interval '120' minute
        AND ROWNUM = 1;
        IF l_exists = 1 THEN
            raise_application_error(-20634, 'This time clashes with another event.');
        END IF;
    END;
end;`

Comment: Fraid not - 2 errors

`3 5 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following: begin function pragma procedure subtype type current curso
7 4 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while`

Comment: I'll put my code as an answer so I can format it properly.  Your help has been invaluable!